# I have some difficulties with my Levels class. What is wrong?

Tags: c#, xna

I wrote the Levels class to store the amount of enemies for each level in it. The Levels class is called once before starting a new level.
For example, if the player chooses Level 1 in the game menu, 5 zombies, 3 spiders and 1 werewolf should be drawn (in another class).
But for the moment, I always get this error message : Method must have a return type.
What is wrong ?

```
public class Levels
{
    int currentLevel, Zombies, Spiders, Werewolfs;

    public Levels(int Level)
    {
        this.currentLevel = Level;
    }

     public Level1()
    {
        Zombies = 5;
        Spiders = 3;
        Werewolfs = 1;
    }

     public Level2()
    {
        Zombies = 8;
        Spiders = 4;
        Werewolfs = 2;
    }

     public Level3()
    {
        Zombies = 12;
        Spiders = 4;
        Werewolfs = 3;
    }

    public void Load(ContentManager content)
    {
     if (currentLevel == 1)
       Level1();

     if (currentLevel == 2)
       Level2();

     if (currentLevel == 3)
       Level3();   
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to put void before your Level1,Level2,Level3 methods?

Comment: You cannot have constructors that are named differently, The IDE expects methods. If you want to use it like this, just put the void in front of the method name. For instance: public void Level1() ...

Comment: You can read about methods and to properly declare them [at this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx).

Comment: This is not directly related, but you may want to consider a more descriptive name for your variables. `Zombies` sounds like a collection of objects. `ZombieCount` would give a better sense of what the variable represents. As the size of your code increases, small details like these become more important for maintainability. http://www.makinggoodsoftware.com/2009/05/04/71-tips-for-naming-variables/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Level1(), Level2() etc must have a return type, like void. They are methods not constructors.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't returning anything from your functions. Notice your `Load()` function, it is declared as `public void` which means nothing or "void" is returned from that function. If you are not going to return anything from these functions, include `void` in their declaration. If you are, do something like this:

```
public int Level1()
{
    int Zombies = 5;
    return Zombies;
}
```

Note: Functions can only return one object.

I do not know proper c# syntax so this may be wrong, but the concept is the same.

If you do not want to return something from these functions, declare them as `void`, set global variables for your "enemies" and then use the methods (functions) to alter the global variable.